# Compiling: [Error] array type has incomplete element type

Tags: c, gcc, struct, compilation

I'm having a problem with a program I am trying to complete, as far as I was aware, i had defined the structs correctly, but when compiling I get this error code 3 times, once for each struct

Error message:

```
    34  18 - [Error] array type has incomplete element type
```

My code is shown below, any advice would be extremely appreciated, there's approx 300 lines of code in the full program, let me know if you need to see it, I didn't want to overload you guys with it. Thanks again.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void fileRead();
    void readGrades();
    void readResults();
    void pointCompute();
    void sortGrades();
    void print();

    typedef struct{
        char subject[15];
        char level[2];
        char grade[3];
        int points[3];
    } temp;
    typedef struct{
        char subject[15];
        char level[2];
        char grade[3];
        int points[3];
    } grades;

    typedef struct{
        char subject[15];
        char level[2];
        char grade[3];
        int points[3];
    } results;
    struct temp temp[50];
    struct grades grades[50];
    struct results results[50];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they are typedefs, remove the `struct` from the variable definition lines. You put `struct` if the types are actual structs, not typedefs. Also, the variable names cannot be the same as the type names.

```
temp temp_var[50];
grades grades_var[50];
results results_var[50];
```

Comment: I see the variables themselves have the same identifiers as the typedefs, you can't do that. Change the names of the variables

Comment: That's a great help, thank you for your quick and clear response! :)

Comment: Note that variable names can have same names as type names (not including int,char,etc. because they are also keywords), but they have to be declared in inner scope. This is known as shadowing, in this case variable name will shadow type name. BTW even if it's legal, it's bad idea to use same name for variables and types.